# How to distribute lengthy text in a table

Tags: support, mathjax

How can I make the first row of second column be like the following in the below table?

"8-Bit Representation

(ordinary 8-bit binary

if nonnegative or 8-bit two's

complement of absolute value if negative)"

$$\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c||c|}
\hline
Integer & \text {8-Bit Representation(ordinary 8-bit binary if nonnegative or 8-bit two's complement of absolute value if negative}) & P \implies Q \\ \hline
T & T & T  \\ 
T & F & F  \\ 
F & T & T  \\ 
F & F & T  \\ \hline
\end{array} $$

Comment: Is it really, absolutely necessary to have all this text in the heading? Myself I would just write "8-bit representation" in the heading and write the explanation outside of the table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using array once again in the cell of the table?

$$\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c||c|}
\hline
Integer & \begin{array}{l}\text {8-Bit Representation}\\\text{(ordinary 8-bit binary}\\\text{ if nonnegative or 8-bit two's}\\\text{complement of absolute value if negative)}\end{array} & P \implies Q \\ \hline
T & T & T  \\
T & F & F  \\
F & T & T  \\
F & F & T  \\ \hline
\end{array} $$

`$$\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c||c|}
\hline
Integer & \begin{array}{l}\text {8-Bit Representation}\\\text{(ordinary 8-bit binary}\\\text{ if nonnegative or 8-bit two's}\\\text{complement of absolute value if negative)}\end{array} & P \implies Q \\ \hline
T & T & T  \\
T & F & F  \\
F & T & T  \\
F & F & T  \\ \hline
\end{array} $$`

An alternative solution would be to give the explanation of the second column in the text, not in the header of the table.

The fact that arrays can be nested is also mentioned in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5044#5044) in MathJax tutorial.

Comment: The inner array should be left aligned.

Comment: I have edited {c} to {l} per your suggestion.